# How can I move a specific folder if there is a file with the same name in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell scriptthat finds a specific file and moves it to a folder.

```
    #!/bin/sh
echo -n "/home/cosmoretro/movie/"
        read text2
while :
        do
        echo -n "Ara:"
        read text1
        b=$(find /home/cosmoretro 2>/dev/null -iname "$text1"*)
        IFS=$'\n'
    mv $b /home/cosmoretro/movie/"$text2"
done
```

But it moves files as well if there is a file same as folder I search.

All I want is only moving folder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time even reading this script. May I suggest you rewrite it a little?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "/home/cosmoretro/movie/"
read destinationFileName

while :
do
    echo -n "Ara:"
    read sourceFileName
    sourceFile=$(find /home/cosmoretro -type d -iname "$sourceFileName" -print -quit 2> /dev/null)
    if [[ -z $sourceFile ]]; then
        echo "No file named $sourceFileName found"
    else
        mv -- "$sourceFile" /home/cosmoretro/movie/"$destinationFileName"  
    fi
done
```

What I've done:

- Use descriptive names like `destinationFileName` instead of `text2`
- Indent properly
- Make `find` only find directories by specifying `-type d`. If you want to move files only, use `-type f` instead of `-type d`.
- Move redirection to the end of a command as it's not important
- Stop `find` after it's found the first file (`-quit`)
- Remove the superfluous `*` in the `find` command – not sure what you'd want with it there. If you intended for filenames to have wildcards (e.g. searching for `foo` would return `foobar`), then you need to put the wildcard *into* the quotes, i.e. `"$sourceFileName*"`.
- Check if there was a file found at all with `-z` testing if the result is empty.
- Safeguard `mv` against filenames starting with `-` by using the end of options option `--`
- Quote arguments properly to prevent whitespace from breaking the command (no need to change `IFS` then)

Comment: I agree that the OP’s script is very hard to read (and the entire question is very hard to understand), but I speculate that (s)he said `"$text1"*` so she could type a unique initial substring of the name into the script; e.g., type `sco` to find a file/directory named `scofflaw`. Strictly speaking, the output from `find /home/cosmoretro … -print …` will always begin with `/home/cosmoretro/`, so, even if it’s something like `/home/cosmoretro/-r`, it shouldn’t be a problem. But I agree, it’s better to get in the habit of doing things the safe way.

Comment: You're right, but… as you said, better to "just do it" rather than having to think about the special cases. Same goes for double-quoting.